# How to iterate trough a list of web elements that is refreshing every 10 sec?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to iterate through a list that refreshes every 10 sec.

this is what I have tried:

```
driver.get("https://www.winmasters.ro/ro/live-betting/")

events = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.event-wrapper.v1.event-live.odds-hidden.event-sport-1')
for i in range(len(events)):
    try:
        event = events[i]
        name = event.find_element_by_css_selector('.event-details-team-name.event-details-team-a')# the error occurs here
    except: # NoSuchElementException or StaleElementReferenceException 
        time.sleep(3) # i have tried up to 20 sec
        event = events[i]        
        name = event.find_element_by_css_selecto('.event-details-team-name.event-details-team-a')
```

this did not work so I tried another except

```
    except: # second try that also did not work
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.event-details-team-name.event-details-team-a'))
        )
        name = event.find_element_by_css_selecto('.event-details-team-name.event-details-team-a')
```

Now I am assigning something that I will never use to `name` like:

```
try:
    event = events[i]
    name = event.find_element_by_css_selector('.event-details-team-name.event-details-team-a')
except:
    name = "blablabla"
```

With this code when the page refreshes I get about 7 or 8 of the "blablabla" until it finds my selector again from the webpage

Comment: what is the exception? do `except as e: print(e)`

Comment: @MosheSlavin i wrote the exceptions as comments there are 2 :NoSuchElementException or StaleElementReferenceException

Comment: you have repeated typos where selector is written as selecto. Also, is there an URL for testing?

Comment: What element type are you trying to locate? Graph, list...
Do the elements have static prefix or any string that you can locate by css with contain keyword?

Comment: Please provide website and clarify what is your goal? You want to get text of list elements one time or continuously get elements.

Comment: @Sers I updated the question to include website and class names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all required data using JavaScript.
Code below will give you list of events `map` with all details instantly and without `NoSuchElementException` or `StaleElementReferenceException` errors:
**me_id** : unique identificator
**href** : href with details which you can use to get details
**team_a** : name of the first team
**team_a_score** : score of the first team
**team_b** : name of the second team
**team_b_score** : score of the second team
**event_status** : status of the event
**event_clock** : time of the event

```
def events = driver.execute_script('return [...document.querySelectorAll(\'[data-uat="live-betting-overview-leagues"] .events-for-league .event-live\')].map(e=>{return {me_id:e.getAttribute("me_id"), href:e.querySelector("a.event-details-live").href, team_a:e.querySelector(".event-details-team-a").textContent, team_a_score:e.querySelector(".event-details-score-1").textContent, team_b:e.querySelector(".event-details-team-b").textContent, team_b_score:e.querySelector(".event-details-score-2").textContent, event_status:e.querySelector(\'[data-uat="event-status"]\').textContent, event_clock:e.querySelector(\'[data-uat="event-clock"]\').textContent}})')
for event in events:
    print(event.get('me_id'))
    print(event.get('href')) #using href you can open event details using: driver.get(event.get('href'))
    print(event.get('team_a'))
    print(event.get('team_a_score'))
    print(event.get('team_b'))
    print(event.get('team_b_score'))
    print(event.get('event_status'))
    print(event.get('event_clock'))
```

Comment: No, there’s no java. Try it

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`  I tried to find it but i can't

Comment: Error `invalid assignment left-hand side` i do not know javascript code so i do not understand these errors sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185819/discussion-between-sers-and-rius2).

Answer (score 1):

One primary problem is that you are acquiring all of the elements up front, and then iterating through that list. As the page itself is updating frequently, the elements you've already acquired have gone "stale", meaning they are not long associated with current DOM objects. When you try to use those stale elements, Selenium throw StaleElementReferenceExceptions because it has no way of doing anything with those now out-of-date objects.

One way to overcome this is to only acquire and use an element right as you need it, rather than fetching them all up front. I personally feel the cleanest approach is to use the CSS [`:nth-child()`](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_nth-child.asp) approach:

```
from selenium import webdriver


def main():
    base_css = '.event-wrapper.v1.event-live.odds-hidden.event-sport-1'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        driver.get("https://www.winmasters.ro/ro/live-betting/")

        # Get a list of all elements
        events = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(base_css)
        print("Found {} events".format(len(events)))

        # Iterate through the list, keeping track of the index
        # note that nth-child referencing begins at index 1, not 0
        for index, _ in enumerate(events, 1):
            name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("{}:nth-child({}) {}".format(
                base_css,
                index,
                '.event-details-team-name.event-details-team-a'
            ))
            print(name.text)
    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I run the above script, I get this output:

```
$ python script.py
Found 2 events
Hapoel Haifa
FC Ashdod
```

Now, as the underlying webpage really does update a lot, there is still a decent chance you can get a SERE error. To overcome that you can use a retry decorator (`pip install retry` to get the package) to handle the SERE and reacquire the element:

```
import retry
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException


@retry.retry(StaleElementReferenceException, tries=3)
def get_name(driver, selector):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
    return elem.text


def main():
    base_css = '.event-wrapper.v1.event-live.odds-hidden.event-sport-1'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        driver.get("https://www.winmasters.ro/ro/live-betting/")

        events = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(base_css)
        print("Found {} events".format(len(events)))
        for index, _ in enumerate(events, 1):
            name = get_name(
                driver,
                "{}:nth-child({}) {}".format(
                    base_css,
                    index,
                    '.event-details-team-name.event-details-team-a'
                )
            )
            print(name)
    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, despite the above examples, I think you still have issues with your CSS selectors, which is the primary reason for the NoSuchElement exceptions. I can't help with that without a better description of what you are actually trying to accomplish with this script.

Comment: I am scraping data teams, odds and sometimes i click one event and scrap some odds from there and store it all in a database and do some statistics from that data